# Windows raises multiple windows when switching to one window after Start-D

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

Here's something that's been bothering me about Windows for years. It's been going on since XP and now in Windows 7 too.

I often use <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all windows. (There's also a button that does this on the tray, for people who prefer to use the mouse.) This is a great feature. However, sometimes, after using <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, I'll want to switch to one window. I'll use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to it, but then Windows will un-minimize a bunch of other windows that were minimized before!

Is it possible to prevent this from happening and have just the single window un-minimized?

Comment: `Cannot repro.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As The Old New Thing writes in **["What is the difference between Minimize All and Show Desktop?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/27/143042.aspx)**, the *Show Desktop* function will hide all windows, including *non-minimizable* ones, by raising the desktop window on top of all of them. But the desktop always tries to return to the bottom (to avoid "losing" windows that might not be listed in the taskbar), so this means that windows which cannot be minimized will become visible again.

Does this match your problem?

Comment: That makes sense. I guess it depends on what his definition of *a bunch of other windows* is. On the one hand, it seems to indicate that only *some* extraneous windows are restored, not all. On the other hand, windows with no minimize button are non-standard, and it seems unlikely that anyone would have numerous, unrelated windows with no minimize button just floating around the desktop.

Comment: Hmm, that sucks. Start-M fails for many windows (e.g. Winamp, and it seems to have a problem with multi-monitor setups.) I really wish there was a hybrid of Start-D and Start-M that on one hand, worked on all windows, but on the other hand doesn't cause all windows to pop back up after switching to one.